# Why does gazebo contact sensor topic stops publishing on deleting and respawning the object to whch the contact sensor is atached?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a box object model to which I have attached a contact sensor, following this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=contact_sensor#SetupTutorial). On spawning the object in gazebo, initially I get the contact sensor data on the topic `/gazebo/default/blue_box1/link/my_contact`. However, when I delete this object and re-spawn it, no data is published on this topic, and I just get the following

```
> Msg Waiting for master Msg Connected
> to gazebo master @
> http://127.0.0.1:11345 Msg Publicized
> address: 192.168.5.30
```

Please help me in debugging this issue. I have already added the update rate in the sensor, so that may not be the cause. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14846/why-does-gazebo-contact-sensor-topic-stops-publishing-on-deleting-and-respawning-the-object-to-whch-the-contact-sensor-is-atached?/) by [SP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2519/sp/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 27 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This problem *may* have been resolved with [this pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-requests/2494). You can try compiling gazebo from source, using the `gazebo7` branch, or wait for a new gazebo7 debian release.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2519/sp/) on 2016-11-21**:
Thank you; previously I was using Gazebo 2 which comes with ROS Indigo. I integrated ROS Indigo with Gazebo7, and now this problem seems to be resolved.